# Сохранение картинок с личного сайта

Tags: вёрстка

Есть личный сайт, на конструкторе wfolio, раньше была возможность включать и отключать сохранение фото для пользователя правой кнопкой мыши, сейчас её отключили в обычных страницах (https://artcone.ru/infinity), но включили возможность сохранения через создание блога. Этот момент меня смущает.
Возможно существует какой-то код, который можно вставить на сайт и заработает сохранение снимков для других пользователей с обычных, не блоговых страниц? Просто, если посмотреть изнутри, когда работаешь с сайтом, то всё на этом конструкторе через... Также картинки с сайта не индексируются в яндекс картинках, все слова прописаны, но яндекс их не видит.

Помогите разобраться, я не программист!
Админы конструктора говороят, всё хорошо)

Comment: не знаю, что это за конструктор сайтов, но авторов его нужно лишить права кодить. Блокировка контексного меню - самое наивное, что можно сделать. Найдите на фриланс биржах любого маломальского js разработчика, пусть отключить context menu и будет все хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь поискать)

Answer (score 0):

"Все мы стоим на плечах гигантов".

К чему я это? Уважаемый KoVadim уже проделал за нас всю работу - посмотрел, каким образом реализован "запрет"

Подозреваю, что то, о что советует KoVadim - можно сделать с помощью [такого расширения для Хрома](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo)   с говорящим названием Allow Right-Click.

Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо! Но мне нужно включить такую возможность, чтобы другие люди, мои клиенты не задумываясь сохраняли фото с помощью обычной мышки.

Comment: А, понял... Хм. Интересно, понятно, что вроде бы это делается при помощи какого то простого js вроде описанного в ответе здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335136

Comment: Спасибо большое!